# Is there a word for "too much time (more than necessary)"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

A good word that would replace the following sentence:

> I spend too much time on youtube.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a single word that means "I spend too much time on youtube"? Or did you just want a word to replace "spend too much"?

Comment: +1 for at least using youtube and not ELU in your sentence! Here's two ways to shorten it, but they're probably not correct, so they'll stay where they belong, here in the comments: "I'm hooked on youtube." or I'm addicted to youtube."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**exorbitant**

> exceeding the bounds of custom, propriety, or reason, especially in amount or extent; highly excessive

**inordinate**

> not within proper or reasonable limits; immoderate; excessive

**unreasonable**

> excessive, immoderate, or exorbitant; unconscionable

I would see all these three as stronger than **too much**.

Answer (score 5):

*Waste* might be a good choice

> I waste too much time on youtube

*Waste* and *spend* share similarities in meaning, but waste implies that you shouldn't be spending so much.

Comment: I think that's close to the answer, if not it, but just "I waste time on youtube" would make it shorter and, IMO keep the accurate notion that waste implies too much